# Sql query where condition with dates

Tags: sql

So, i have this query here:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT formas.*, SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET, SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,SMS_SERVISI.time_added,servis_furnitor.id_servis,servis_furnitor.furnitori,servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja
FROM formas  
LEFT JOIN servis_furnitor ON formas.furnitori = servis_furnitor.id_servis 
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET 
ORDER BY formas.id DESC 
WHERE $today-formas.data_fillim > servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja";
```

The last row is wrong i know, i mean i'm okay up to there..
I have this orders, they have a starting date which is  `formas.data_fillim` and i have the today's date :

```
$today = date("Ymd");
```

So the difference between  `$today-formas.data_fillim` shouldn't be bigger than `servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja` which is an integer itself and it shows the number of days

```
formas.data_fillim
```

is a datetype..

I need to extract all data whose difference with today's date and their starting day isn't bigger than the number of days predefined in "kohezgjatja"

Any help please..
Thanks

UPDATES

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());  


echo $strSQL = "SELECT  formas.*,
        SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET,
        SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,
        SMS_SERVISI.time_added,
        servis_furnitor.id_servis,
        servis_furnitor.furnitori,
        servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja
FROM formas
LEFT JOIN servis_furnitor
        ON formas.furnitori = servis_furnitor.id_servis
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI
        ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET
WHERE DATEDIFF ( day , '$today' , formas.data_fillim ) > servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja
ORDER BY formas.id DESC"
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause should be _before_ the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks..but well, the query is wrong anyways, the last part :)

Comment: Different database systems do date math differently.  Please specify yours.

Comment: Could you please see my updated question?
i added the query but something isn't right.. i mean maybe i'm not getting the difference between the days..

Comment: In what language are you writing `echo $strSQL = "SELECT...` ? It looks like you need to build the $today variable into something like `... ( day , '" +$today+ "' , formas.data_fillim ) ...` or just use `... ( day , GetDate() , formas.data_fillim ) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format of a `SELECT` statement is

```
SELECT ....
FROM...
WHERE ...
GROUP ....
ORDER BY...
```

so in your case,

```
SELECT  formas.*,
        SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET,
        SMS_SERVISI.MBYLLUR,
        SMS_SERVISI.time_added,
        servis_furnitor.id_servis,
        servis_furnitor.furnitori,
        servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja
FROM formas
LEFT JOIN servis_furnitor
        ON formas.furnitori = servis_furnitor.id_servis
LEFT JOIN SMS_SERVISI
        ON formas.ID = SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET
WHERE DATEDIFF ( day , $TODAY , formas.data_fillim )  > servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja
ORDER BY formas.id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue, i mean i know it's wrong the query.. but i get an error like :
 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: Look up DateDiff http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx and DateAdd, and other date functions from the list on the left there.

Comment: what is `kohezgjatja`? is it a date or int?

Comment: this is what i get if i print it:

SMS_SERVISI.IDTICKET WHERE DATEDIFF ( day , 20130223 , formas.data_fillim ) > servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja

Comment: maybe i should change the $today variable?

Comment: Could you please see my updated question?
i added the query but something isn't right.. i mean maybe i'm not getting the difference between the days..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
where formas.data_fillim <= DateAdd(day, servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja, getdate())
```

You may have to put a minus sign in front of servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja, depending on what you store there.

Comment: Thanks..
i insert something like this:
where formas.data_fillim <= DateAdd($today, servis_furnitor.kohezgjatja, getdate())

it says wrong argument provided..

Comment: @pyetjegoo: Please see [`DATEADD()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) if you are indeed using SQL Server.

Comment: Could you please see my updated question?
i added the query but something isn't right.. i mean maybe i'm not getting the difference between the days..

Comment: You can experiment here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2949/11 along the lines of `SELECT DATEDIFF( day, GetDate(), '2013-2-27') as Diffence`